# Ant design sort table code not working on the react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I used following  **[ant design  sort table code](https://ant-design.gitee.io/components/table/)** in react type script, its not working correctly anyone know how to do that correctly

**My code here**

```
     import { Table } from 'antd';
  import * as React from 'react';

import { Table } from 'antd';
const columns = [
    {
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        filters: [
            {
                text: 'Joe',
                value: 'Joe',
            },
            {
                text: 'Jim',
                value: 'Jim',
            },
            {
                text: 'Submenu',
                value: 'Submenu',
                children: [
                    {
                        text: 'Green',
                        value: 'Green',
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Black',
                        value: 'Black',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
        // specify the condition of filtering result
        // here is that finding the name started with `value`
        onFilter: (value:any, record:any) => record.name.indexOf(value) === 0,
        sorter: (a:any, b:any) => a.name.length - b.name.length,
        sortDirections: ['descend'],
    },
    {
        title: 'Age',
        dataIndex: 'age',
        defaultSortOrder: 'descend',
        sorter: (a:any, b:any) => a.age - b.age,
    },
    {
        title: 'Address',
        dataIndex: 'address',
        filters: [
            {
                text: 'London',
                value: 'London',
            },
            {
                text: 'New York',
                value: 'New York',
            },
        ],
        filterMultiple: false,
        onFilter: (value:any, record:any) => record.address.indexOf(value) === 0,
        sorter: (a:any, b:any) => a.address.length - b.address.length,
        sortDirections: ['descend', 'ascend'],
    },
];

const data = [
    {
        key: '1',
        name: 'John Brown',
        age: 32,
        address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
    },
    {
        key: '2',
        name: 'Jim Green',
        age: 42,
        address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
    },
    {
        key: '3',
        name: 'Joe Black',
        age: 32,
        address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
    },
    {
        key: '4',
        name: 'Jim Red',
        age: 32,
        address: 'London No. 2 Lake Park',
    },
];
function onChange(pagination:any, filters:any, sorter:any, extra:any) {
    console.log('params', pagination, filters, sorter, extra);
}
//Table sample data
export class Customertable extends React.Component {


    render() {
        return (

            /* Start Search button*/
            <div className="customertable-section">
                <div>
                    <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} onChange={onChange} />

                </div>


            </div>
            /* End of  Search button*/
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While declaring the variable in typescript, you need to give it like, `columns: any = []` and `data: any = []`..

And while making `table` , you should give the props like,

```
<Table columns={this.columns} dataSource={this.data} />
```

**[Working sample antd table with typescript here...](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-669cv)**

Comment: Is there not static typing for Column Config?

Comment: Using `any` is a hack and not a solution.

Comment: the linked example doesn't sort. so it is not working sample.

Answer (score 3):

To add on to Maniraj's comment, the documentation provides a section for Typescript specific usage:
https://ant.design/components/table/#Using-in-TypeScript

Setting the type of `columns` is possible by importing `ColumnsType` from `'antd/es/table'`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply sort your **ant design table's column** by replace your old code with new:

**Old Code:**

```
sorter: (a:any, b:any) => a.name.length - b.name.length,
```

**New Code:**

```
sorter: (a:any, b:any) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name),
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution that may help someone. You should write type for your table config using default ant types and then in compare func, your item is DefaultRecordType, func returns number.

```js
const TABLE_COLUMNS: ColumnsType<DefaultRecordType> = [
  {
    title: 'ISO #',
    dataIndex: 'iso',
    key: 'iso',
    sorter: (a: DefaultRecordType, b: DefaultRecordType): number =>
      a.iso.localeCompare(b.iso),
  },]
```